# How to resolve:- "Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" in VS Code windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, mingw, permission-denied

I'm facing the error:- "---Path to the bin folder of compiler---:cannot open output file queue_array.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status".
-->This is the *issue on VS Code* I tried other IDEs such as *'Codes Block'* the same compiler is working fine there.
--> I'm facing this issue whenever I'm *Killing one Terminal* and then compile the program again.
--> As I changed the folder where I was working the *code was compiled* once and then after killing the terminal and compiling the code again, the same error is showing.
--> *I doubt that when I'm killing the terminal it is not actually ending the process and is still running somewhere in the background.* 
--> I had already tried reinstalling the compiler and the Vs Code. Also tried compiling different programs but same error after *killing the terminal once*
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

```
struct Queue {
int front, rear, capacity;
int* queue;
Queue(int c)
{
    front = rear = 0;
    capacity = c;
    queue = new int;
}

~Queue() { delete[] queue; }

void queueEnqueue(int data)
{
    if (capacity == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is full\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        queue[rear] = data;
        rear++;
    }
    return;
}
void queueDequeue()
{

    if (front == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is empty\n");
        return;
    }

    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < rear - 1; i++) {
            queue[i] = queue[i + 1];
        }

        rear--;
    }
    return;
}

void queueDisplay()
{
    int i;
    if (front == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = front; i < rear; i++) {
        printf(" %d <-- ", queue[i]);
    }
    return;
}

void queueFront()
{
    if (front == rear) {
        printf("\nQueue is Empty\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\nFront Element is: %d", queue[front]);
    return;
}
```

};

int main(void)
{

```
Queue q(4);

q.queueDisplay();

q.queueEnqueue(20);
q.queueEnqueue(30);
q.queueEnqueue(40);
q.queueEnqueue(50);

q.queueDisplay();

q.queueEnqueue(60);

q.queueDisplay();

q.queueDequeue();
q.queueDequeue();

printf("\n\nafter two node deletion\n\n");

q.queueDisplay();

q.queueFront();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your process is still executed and loaded into memory, therefore Windows locks it to avoid any overwrite that may lead to strange things - like if you try to load resources from the executable dynamically during program's lifetime. This behavior cannot be avoided on Windows.

If your program detachs itself from its parent, then killing the parent (i.e. the terminal) won't kill it, and this is perfectly normal. It's the same if the process is launched, THEN attached to a terminal for its outputs - killing the terminal is like killing the child process, it won't affect your program either. On Linux, if I remember well, running it with `&` performs such a detach. On Windows, the `start` command can do the same, and most of the time, running a graphical program from a command line also detach the executed process from the console - usually, you'll see the prompt showing immediately after launching your program.

Globally, you shouldn't just kill a program: you should have a correct method to handle its exit. It depends on what you do, if it's a graphical interface or a console executable, if it's threaded or not, and so on.
Usually, for console applications, `Ctrl+C` is enough to kill it, but you can also monitor `stdin` and/or `stdout` and exit if they are closed. Beware also if you implemented signal handlers, they may prevent your program from closing normally.

Need more of your program to fully reply and give "the" solution.

Comment: Please have a look at the code. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-implementation-of-queue-simple/)

Comment: @YashRaj Yeah, it shouldn't do anything weird... And it should be executed in less than a single second, too, so I barely understand WHY you may need to kill the process! So, it may be something weird in your VSCode configuration... Do you execute the program natively, or on a remote machine?

Comment: On a **remote machine**

Comment: @YashRaj If you kill the terminal (on your LOCAL machine), why the heck should it kill the program on the REMOTE machine? But more important, why do you need to kill a program that should run for a fraction of time, then exit? What happens exactly to require a kill?

Comment: I'm using **google drive cloud storage** to store all the programs since I'm very beginner in the programing. I'm using google drive desktop application which allocate the *15GB of google drive* as a driver in my device and then it keep syncing the work in background, but suddenly this error occurred from somewhere. It was working fine like for months and now today suddenly this error is shown in every code I compile present in that google drive. 
   Yes you are right as the program is running *when I saved the program on my device disk and compiled it, it was working all well.*

Comment: If you have any idea to resolve this please tell and, thankyou for giving your valuable time to this silly problem. This really helped me a lot.

Comment: @YashRaj In fact, I don't even understand why you're on a Google Drive for that: syncing data may lock files unexpectedly... You need to develop in a **LOCAL** directory, to avoid such problems (usually, I even forbid my antivirus to scan my development folders!). And if you need to sync something, you do it _manually_ when needed... I wouldn't chose a Google Drive for that, I prefer to use something designed for it (SVN, Git, Mercurial, ...) so you can keep history, too, and get diffs and/or multiple forks. Using SCM is another question, read a bit about it before - it's easy, don't panic.

Comment: Thankyou, I'm really thankful for your suggestion and telling the proper method for saving files. 